# Cannot create EVENT LOG under ASP .NET MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to create simple Log and use this method but I get an error about Admin. rights.
How is it possible? I see the app. has all admin rights.

```
public static void WriteToEventLog(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                string cs = "WebReports";
                EventLog elog = new EventLog();

                if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs + "Source", cs + "Log");
                }

                elog.Source = cs;
                elog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                elog.WriteEntry(message);
            }
            catch
            {
                  // ERROR OCCURES
            }
        }
```

Any clue thanks!

Comment: You need to copy and paste the exact error your receiving.

Comment: "I see the app. has all admin rights." Really? Your Worker Process is running as an account with the Administrator permissions?

Comment: @vcsjones I just checked Permissions context menu over WebSite and I see that it is in Administrators group. And it has all rights there.

Comment: @Peretz I believe what you are looking at is that Administrators have *access* to it, it doesn't mean it is running as an Administrator. What identity is your App Pool running as?

Comment: @vcsjones It has own App Pool not the default one. Because it works under MS Windows Server 2003

Comment: @Peretz Yes, and what is the *Identity* of the App Pool? (Look on the Identity tab of the App Pool) - is it a custom account that you made, or NETWORK SERVICE?